# pointer in c++ not showing proper values

Tags: c++, pointers

i got 3 linked list and union function

`a` `b` and result are lists i want to fill result list with elements but it is always empty.

main is `result.UnionSets(a,b)` function is

```
void UnionSets(linkedlist & l1, linkedlist & l2)
{       
    node<type> *temp=   l1.tail;
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
        while(temp->next!=tail)
        {
            AddNode(temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;            
        }
    }
    temp=l2.tail;
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
        while(temp->next!=tail)
        {
            AddNode(temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is not clear and wouldn't compile, can you post the code as it is?

Comment: What does any of this even mean? What are you trying to do? `UnionSets` sounds lime it should create a new linked list which contains the elements of the first two lists.

Comment: add node is also a function u can ignore that part all i want is to fill some values in result list but its always empty i guess i need to do somethinng like this.add() or this*.add something like that not sure

Comment: Are you allowed to use the C++ Standard Library? It has a `std::list` container and the `std::set_union` algorithm.

Comment: A claim that *"you can ignore that part"* amounts to an assertion that the bug **can not be in any way related to that code**. How sure are you? How sure should *we* be, given that you are asking a question about a pretty common introductory exercise?

Comment: There is no way to tell what is wrong because there is not enough information. We need to be able to read the definitions of the types. The best way is to provide a compilable piece of code that we can test.

Comment: Since this is not homework, use `std::list` and concentrate on the other parts of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to assume some things about your linked list implementation. If my assumptions are wrong, then my answer is wrong, too.

1. You are initializing your `temp` pointers to the `tail` element of their linked lists. The typical nomenclature is to start at `head` and work towards `tail`. Also, it is typical that the in final node has NULL as its next pointer.
2. You are comparing nodes of one linked list to nodes on a different linked list. Are the linked lists actually cross-linked? Or are they actually independent of each other?

Taking those two points into account, try this:

```
void UnionSets(linkedlist & l1, linkedlist & l2)
{       
    node<type> *temp=   l1.head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
            AddNode(temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;            
    }
    temp=l2.head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
            AddNode(temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
static linkedlist Union(linkedlist& A, linkedlist& B)
{
    linkedlist result;
    for(linkedlist::iterator iter = A.begin(); iter != A.end(); ++iter)
    {
       result.append(*iter);
    }
    for(linkedlist::iterator iter = B.begin(); iter != B.end(); ++iter)
    {
       result.append(*iter);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I assume his assignment is homework that has to match the given API, but this is a really good idea.

Comment: Change `linkedlist::iterator` to `node<type>*`, `A.begin()` to `A.head`, `A.end()` to `tail` (or NULL) and `++iter` to `iter = iter->next` and `append` to `AddNode`. All I've done is make it look like clear, sane C++. The benefit being that this could quite easily be made into a template function for a generic container.